# Why isn't the master branch listed in a new git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I create a `git` repository via `git init`.
I do `git branch`.
Problem: I was expecting to see one branch listed, the `Master` branch. But nothing is listed. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should commit anything - that will create `master` branch.

Comment: When I do `git status` I see: `# On branch master Nothing to commit`

Comment: Apparently, `git` know that any commit to be made will be made on `Master` branch, so it is written in status, whereas there can be no branches completely without content, that's why it is not presented in branch list. If you have files you want to commit in this directory (I presume all files), just do `git add --all`, `git commit -am 'initial commit'` - and `git branch` will show you the `Master` (or so it does for me).